How to exclude specific endpoint from API generation
I've read topic
Generate only one specific endpoint from API
But I have a bit different task I want to exclude some specifics endpoint from generation.
Why do I need it? We have an experiment that analytics write open api schema and if they add new endpoint to existing controlller it leads to compile error(it require to implement new method in interface). We want to avoid this error without implementing stub.
Is there way to achieve it ?
I would apreciate example of gradle (build.gradle.kts)

So, according to the documentation you can simply add x-internal:true to the api path definition, and it will be skipped during generation. 
Try this for example:
openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Swagger Petstore
  license:
    name: MIT
paths:
  /pets:
    get:
      # It will be generated
      summary: List all pets
      operationId: listPets
      ...
    post:
      # it will not
      x-internal: true
      summary: Create a pet
      operationId: createPets
      ...
components:
  schemas:
   ...

Just ask your analytics to add this by default when api is in draft phase.

It works wonderful but I can't find this infomation in the link you provided

Quote from docs: FILTER: When set to operationId:addPet|getPetById for example, it will add x-internal:true to operations with operationId not equal to addPet/getPetById (which will have x-internal set to false) so that these operations marked as internal won't be generated. (end of quote)
Tthis means, that the implementation of generator looks for x-internal and make desicion generate or not.

I see that there is FILTER commandline argument and it works via x-internal option.
Is there any detailed documentation about x-internal ?

I don't know actually how x-* "flags" are processed by generator, but i saw this particular piece of description how FILTER works and makes a assumption.
